# ReferenceError: db is not defined in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm beginner in MERN Stack , I'm trying to do this tutorial: https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial

When I want do aggregate like this:

```
db.recordMarks.aggregate([
   {
     $project: {
       Total: { $sum: "$Assign1"}
     }
   }
])
```

in this code:

```
const express = require("express");

// recordRoutes is an instance of the express router.
// We use it to define our routes.
// The router will be added as a middleware and will take control of requests starting with path /record.
const recordRoutes = express.Router();

// This will help us connect to the database
const dbo = require("../db/conn");

// This help convert the id from string to ObjectId for the _id.
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;

 

// This section will help you get a list of all the records.
recordRoutes.route("/recordMarks").get(function (req, res) {
    let db_connect = dbo.getDb("Database");
    db_connect
      .collection("record Marks")
      .find({})
      .toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(result);
      });
  });


// This section will help you get a single record by id
recordRoutes.route("/recordMarks/:id").get(function (req, res) {
    let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
    let myquery = { _id: ObjectId( req.params.id )};
    db_connect
        .collection("record Marks")
        .findOne(myquery, function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.json(result);
        });
  });
  

// This section will help you create a new record.
recordRoutes.route("/recordMarks/add").post(function (req, response) {
    let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
    let myobj = {
      ID :req.body.ID,
      Assign1: req.body.Assign1,
      Assign2: req.body.Assign2,
    };
    db_connect.collection("record Marks").insertOne(myobj, function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        response.json(res);
      });
    });  
    


    db_connect
      .collection("record Marks")
      .updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document updated");
        response.json(res);
      });
  });
   
  

  module.exports = recordRoutes;
```

**It's showing error ReferenceError: db is not defined at Object.**

I don't know not where the problem is in the contact the database or I am doing everything wrong.

Comment: The error is telling you that `db` is not defined. Most likely you're missing the code that defines the database client. You can't just call `db` like you can inside the Mongo CLI. Instead, you need to set up a client, connect to the database server, then get a reference to the database you want to talk to; this is usually what `db` is in JavaScript code.

Comment: The variable `db` is not defined anywhere, are you sure it's not `dbo` in your case?